# set different rates for different products like silver gold woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In woo commerce there is no such thing available to set different prices for a product that adds up together to show total price of the product. 
For example in Silver  rates for silver / Kg are different and manufacturing rates for each product are different.

So for each product on product page i want to mention the total prices of single product mentioning the rates put up for each thing:

```
example (to be shown on product page) - 

silver coin 8gm -   400 Rs  (these rates are on the basis of cost/Gm . Here 50.0/Gm )
manufacturing cost- 110 Rs 
Total prices :      510 Rs
```

Also after all shopping , i also have to apply shipping charges in the cart , depending upon the area etc. Which is not a problem for me. However i need to solve this problem for multiple rates for single product ? any solutions?

Comment: Can't you use **woocommerce-product-addons-bulk-discount** ?

Comment: bulk discount is for discounting i want to add up prices not give discounts.

Comment: this plugin may work but i think it isnt available for free anywhere :(
http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/?utm_source=product&utm_medium=upsell&utm_campaign=wcaddons

Comment: You can get it from [here](https://github.com/BenjaminAdams/WooCommerce-Product-Add-ons-W-Bulk-Discount).